# stopping notifications that I lost the TAG to

Tags: android, service, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

I know to cancel FirebaseJobDispatcher, the code is

FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(driver);

dispatcher.cancelAll();

But unfortunately I scheduled some jobs already, and didn't save the drivers for those past jobs. So the two lines of code above only cancel all *current* jobs scheduled, but not the ones in the past.

**How do I cancel notifications scheduled in the past that I can no longer reach?** Does turning my phone off cancel them? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the app I'm building seems to stop all notifications from the app.